# Facebook Graph API upload photos for public

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully uploaded the photos through Facebook graph API , but the APPS allowing only for friends but it is not viewing for friends of friends.

This is my coding to upload photo into album

```
$photo_details = array('message'=> 'Padswapp Photos','no_story' => 1);
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($t_name["tmp_name"][$i]);
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Can anyone help how i have to upload the photos as Public.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When creating the album you need to set the privacy, bearing in mind you won't be able to upload a photo with privacy that's more open than what the user has chosen for your app when they accepted the Auth dialog.

See the `privacy` parameter of the album object; when [creating an album for a User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#albums) you can set this to whatever the user wants, subject to the caveat above.

From the docs:

> A JSON-encoded object that defines the privacy setting for the album,
>   for example: {"value":"SELF"} (see details below). Only the user can
>   specify the privacy settings for the post.

Then there's a list of the possible combinations of privacy settings you can use